# Element Datepicker shows "yesterday" not as disabled, when timezone is +14

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, element-ui

With a chrome plugin, I changed my timezone to +14. However, I saw that the calendar app is showing wrong disabled dates.

Have a look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXbWKP?editors=1010).

To disable the date, I'm using this formula:

```
disabledDate(time) {
    return  time.getTime() < Date.now() - 8.64e7;
},
```

The problem is that it shows me the 22th as an option to choose. But this should not be the case.

[image]

What is wrong?

**Edit**:

The last value of time is: `Fri Mar 22 2019 13:00:00 GMT+1400 (Pacific Kiritimati Standard Time)`

Now results to: `Sat Mar 23 2019 03:28:21 GMT+1400 (Pacific Kiritimati Standard Time)`

However this leads to false:

```
temp2.getTime() < Date.now() - 8.64e7; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have to close this question. It's the plugins fault. If I'm changing the timezone via the system, everything works fine.